html2canvas download the image like desktop view instead of mobile view for dom content reactjs
In reactjs I am using html2canvas library to capture the screen and download it as an image. Here is the code
const generateImage = async () => {
    const element = contentRef.current;
    const canvas = await html2canvas(element, { scale: 2 });
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const imgBlob = await fetch(imgData).then(res => res.blob());
    const file = new File([imgBlob], 'document.png', { type: 'image/png' });

    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'document.png';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    return file;
  };

On mobile view it capture the html dom content as of mobile view like a vertically long image. Can on mobile i download it like a desktop view?

There's a bug here: you're calling URL.revokeObjectURL(url); prematurely. Only revoke the objectURL after the user is fully done with it. One way to (almost) do this is to only call revokeObjectURL immedaitely before creating a new objectURL.

this is for download, download is working fine but the image is getting generated for mobile view that i need to set for desktop view

I just noticed that you're calling const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); - which is pointless (and dumb: it locks-up the browser because it's synchronous, and data: URIs waste more space than an Escalade). Change your code to use HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob() instead.

@Dai can you add an answer with corerct code? and will this solve the actual issue?

Just to clarify, you're asking if html2canvas can render the page after first doing a full re-layout of the page as though the browser's viewport was sized like 1920x1080px (or so)? That kinda defeats the point of using html2canvas...

is there any other solution for this?

I can't think a good reason why you would want to do that, though. Please explain why you want to do this first.

@Dai i send customer to sign document and then capture the page as image , and on phone it captures the image as portrait or vertically very lengthy image that is hard to read , so I want to capture the document as it opens on desktop

changing view port helped me
const generateImage = async () => {
    // Temporarily set the viewport to a larger size for capturing the content
    const originalViewport = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').getAttribute('content');
    const viewportMeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
    viewportMeta.setAttribute('content', 'width=1440');
  
    // Wait for the viewport to adjust
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 300));
  
    const element = contentRef.current;
    const canvas = await html2canvas(element, { scale: 2 });
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const imgBlob = await fetch(imgData).then(res => res.blob());
    const file = new File([imgBlob], 'document.png', { type: 'image/png' });
  
    // Restore the original viewport
    viewportMeta.setAttribute('content', originalViewport);
    // Wait for the viewport to adjust back
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 300));
    return file;
  };

